# Позиционирование форм

Tags: c#, winforms

Как в WinForms сделать так, чтобы одна форма была позиционирована внутри другой формы и при изменении размеров главной формы, менялись размеры другой формы (дочерней)?

Comment: Подсократил вопрос, убрал лишнее

Comment: Устанавливаете свойство StartPosition в Manual и позиционируете как угодно. Для изменения размеров дочерней формы отслеживайте событие Resize главной формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если бы не странные ограничения фреймворка, можно было бы просто написать `childForm.Parent = parentForm`, но почему-то это запрещено. Но против лома нет приёма, просто воспользуемся функцией `SetParent`. Ну а дальше банально: создаём дочернюю форму, обрабатываем событие `SizeChanged`:

```
partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Form _child;

    public Form1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _child = new Form {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual,
            Left = 20,
            Top = 20,
            Width = ClientSize.Width - 40,
            Height = ClientSize.Height - 40,
        };
        _child.Show(this);
        SetParent(_child.Handle, Handle);
    }

    protected override void OnSizeChanged (EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        _child.Width = ClientSize.Width - 40;
        _child.Height = ClientSize.Height - 40;
    }

    [DllImport ("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent (IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
}
```

Comment: Для чего в вашем решении используется библиотека user32.dll?

Comment: @Vladimir Для вызова [SetParent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms633541.aspx).